# Traversing byte string through uint16_t pointer

Tags: c++

I have a list of `uint16_t`'s that has been packed into a protobuf message that looks like:

```protobuf
bytes values = 1;
```

The generated stubs for this message in C allows me to set the field with some code like:

```
protobufMessage.set_values(uint16ptr, sizeof(uint16_t) * amount);
```

In the above example, `uint16ptr` is a `uint16_t*` to the start of the value list and `amount` is the number of elements in that list.

Now, since I know the message is in the field and I want to be as efficient as possible, I don't want to memcpy as that I want to somehow directly access that memory and I don't want to iterate through the values one by one as cases with a large `amount` value would be slow. So I tried something like:

```
uint16_t *ptr = (uint16_t*) some_string.c_str();
```

This works "fine", however I don't get the same values I originally packed in. I think it might be because I am not traversing the data correctly. How should I do this properly?

Comment: if `some_string` is a `std::string` then this code has undefined behavior.  You could use `memcpy` to copy `c_str()` into a correctly size `uint16_t` buffer

Comment: How did a buffer full of `uint16_t` end up in an `std::string`? `char*` I'll concede, low-level code does weird stuff like that. But you have to go way out of your way to stuff that into an `std::string`.

Comment: `I don't get the same values I wanted` For what string value, what values you want? Or, what are the rules? Please post sample input and sample output you want to get, please post the output you are getting right now. `I am not traversing the data correctly`You have not showed such code. Please post an [MCVE]. `How should I do this properly?` So are the uint16_t encoded in little endian or big endian?

Comment: For more clarification, I packed the uint16_t values into a protobuf bytes message, and the output of said message is a std::string. The output isn’t what I want as the numbers I originally packed into the bytes message came out as different values.

Comment: That makes sense. And since you packed the string, then you know the order the `uint16_t` hi / lo bytes need to be unpacked. Why not use an indexed loop to extract two bytes at a time from the `.c_str()` restoring the array/vector of `uint16_t`? In order for anyone to give a concrete answer, we would need to see how the bytes were packed to confirm the order they need to be unpacked in. A minimum reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, I thought about it but I feel like re-traversing through the memory block 2 bytes at a time would be slow in cases where there are many values. I want to see if it's possible to directly use that memory as it already exists within the protobuf message.

Comment: I'm not sure, but assigning the result of c_str() to another pointer (regardless of type) might be problematic if the string goes out of scope or reallocates before you can flush the protobuf.

Comment: The issue is the order the bytes were packed on the protobuf end and whether there is a difference in endianness that needs to be handled. If the `uint16_t` bytes were packed lo, hi but the machine was big endian and the receiving side is little endian, the byte order will be reversed. Ideally they are always packed and transmitted big endian so there is never a question of the byte order received.

Comment: Have you considered using a `repeated int32` field instead of `bytes`?  Your program will use more memory, but the encoded message itself likely won't be much, if any, bigger and the generated interface code will be easier to work with.

Comment: `into a protobuf bytes message` Then use protobuf to unpack it. It's a encoding, with a header and key-value pairs. https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protobuf encodes your message so you can't simply read the values back from a string. But a "repeated" uint16_t should be a big blob somewhere in the message. If you knew the offset you could access the data there.

But that is still UB since the uint16_t in the protobuf message are not aligned. So on some CPUs this will be just slow, on others it will trap. The only safe way is to memcpy the data. Use the function provided by protobuf to extract the uint16_t's.

Note: Strictly speaking it's even worse since there are no objects of type uint16_t living in the message so any access would be UB. But it being a fundemantal type makes it ok-ish, if it weren't for the alignment.